# How to select a specific array number in a for each loop ASP Classic

Tags: arrays, foreach, asp-classic

I am programming a select box in which a user can select from multiple values (up to 72). Im population the select box by using a for each loop to go through the array, like so:

```
For Each item In myArray 

ItemUur = PadDigits(Hour(item),2)
ItemMinuut = PadDigits(Minute(item),2)
ItemTotaal = ItemUur & ":" & ItemMinuut
%>
    <OPTION NAME="van" VALUE="<%=ItemTotaal%>"><%=ItemTotaal %></OPTION>    
<%
Next
```

The array are time values (I am using the paddigits function to output the time as 05:00).

This works great. Though I want the select box to start at a default value, which isnt the first array (05:00) but instead the 10th array value (07:30).

I tried accomplishing this like so:

```
<OPTION NAME="van" VALUE="<%=ItemTotaal%>"><%=ItemTotaal(10) %></OPTION>
```

This is not working so then I thought I should be using the original array so I tried with `item(10)` as well, got the same error though..

The error message I am receiving is:
`type mismatch 'item' / 'ItemTotaal'` (depends on which I am using)

How can I get this to work?

Comment: Start at the 10th item or set the 10th item as selected ? You could use a counter within the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<OPTION NAME="van"><%=myArray(10)%></OPTION>
```

ItemTotaal in your case -- just variable (not array)

myArray in your case -- array. so need to use it for access items in array

error you get because you are trying to use "Not Array" variable as Array variable

Answer (score 0):

You were trying to use the variable as array.

The format should be as ArrayName(ArrayElementPosition)

```
    <OPTION NAME="van" VALUE="<%=myArray(9) %>"><%=myArray(9) %></OPTION>
```

Note: to get the 10th element, i have mentioned as myArray(9) instead of myArray(10) as the array starts its position in 0.

Hope this helps.